# gcc on windows generating garbage? windows vs linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, assembly, mingw

I'm trying to find out why in windows has so much more instructions for the same program than linux.
So I just used `int a=0xbeef;` and  `printf("test\n");` in C and compiled in Linux and Windows. When I debug and disassembly the main frame I got this:
On linux:

```
0x080483e4 <+0>:     push   %ebp
0x080483e5 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
0x080483e7 <+3>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x080483ea <+6>:     sub    $0x20,%esp
0x080483ed <+9>:     movl   $0xbeef,0x1c(%esp)
0x080483f5 <+17>:    movl   $0x80484d0,(%esp)
0x080483fc <+24>:    call   0x8048318 <puts@plt>
0x08048401 <+29>:    leave  
0x08048402 <+30>:    ret
```

Ok that's nice. I see the movl 0x1c offset of esp to put the value there.

But in windows I got this:

```
0x401290 <main>:        push   %ebp
0x401291 <main+1>:      mov    %esp,%ebp
0x401293 <main+3>:      sub    $0x18,%esp
0x401296 <main+6>:      and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x401299 <main+9>:      mov    $0x0,%eax
0x40129e <main+14>:     add    $0xf,%eax
0x4012a1 <main+17>:     add    $0xf,%eax
0x4012a4 <main+20>:     shr    $0x4,%eax
0x4012a7 <main+23>:     shl    $0x4,%eax
0x4012aa <main+26>:     mov    %eax,0xfffffff8(%ebp)
0x4012ad <main+29>:     mov    0xfffffff8(%ebp),%eax
0x4012b0 <main+32>:     call   0x401720 <_alloca>
0x4012b5 <main+37>:     call   0x4013c0 <__main>
0x4012ba <main+42>:     movl   $0xbeef,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x4012c1 <main+49>:     movl   $0x403000,(%esp,1)
0x4012c8 <main+56>:     call   0x401810 <printf>
0x4012cd <main+61>:     mov    $0x0,%eax
0x4012d2 <main+66>:     leave
0x4012d3 <main+67>:     ret
```

First of all, I don't know why the windows compiler (mingw) generate so much code. Is 2x more than Linux... this makes me thinking. And another thing: from main+9 to main+37 I can't see the point of that code.

I would thank if someone answer to this, I'm just curious :)

edit:
With -O3 argument on linux I got the same and in windows something like magic happends:

```
0x401290 <main>:        push   %ebp
0x401291 <main+1>:      mov    $0x10,%eax
0x401296 <main+6>:      mov    %esp,%ebp
0x401298 <main+8>:      sub    $0x8,%esp
0x40129b <main+11>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x40129e <main+14>:     call   0x401700 <_alloca>
0x4012a3 <main+19>:     call   0x4013a0 <__main>
0x4012a8 <main+24>:     movl   $0x403000,(%esp,1)
0x4012af <main+31>:     call   0x4017f0 <puts>
0x4012b4 <main+36>:     leave
0x4012b5 <main+37>:     xor    %eax,%eax
0x4012b7 <main+39>:     ret
```

leave then xor then ret. ok :D the call _alloca and call __main still there. and I don't know what is `0x401291 <main+1>:      mov    $0x10,%eax` doing here :D

Comment: Wow. Seems like the compiler on Windows is trolling the ALU.

Comment: It's just boilerplate ABI stuff, but compile with -O3 for both and it may well shrink it down a bit.

Comment: similar weird function prologue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155257/gdb-what-is-the-mysterious-assembly-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be compiling with old 3.x series `gcc`, you'd better upgrade. Newer versions don't invoke `alloca`. I suspect the particular version of `alloca` might use register convention so the `mov 0x10,%eax` is probably setting up the argument for that call.

`__main` is a startup function defined in `crtbegin.o` that executes global constructors and registers a function using `atexit` that will run the global destructors.

Also note that `main` gets special treatment, like the stack alignment code and the above-mentioned initialization. It may be a good idea to instead compare a "plain" function if you are just interested in code generation issues.

Answer (score 0):

One notes that in the upper example the compiler is calling puts, while in the lower it is printf.   I would suspect you have optimization on in the top example, but not on the lower example.

It also might be a debug vs non-debug build.