# Why does this function prologue use several instructions to calculate the esp reduction?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

I have looked at a few dumps of assembler code and there is this section (found [here](http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow3.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080335/stack-contents-during-a-function-call/21096254#21096254)) in the main function:

```
<main+0>:    push   %ebp
<main+1>:    mov    %esp, %ebp
<main+3>:    sub    $0x8, %esp
<main+6>:    and    $0xfffffff0, %esp
<main+9>:    mov    $0x0, %eax
<main+14>:   add    $0xf, %eax
<main+17>:   add    $0xf, %eax
<main+20>:   shr    $0x4, %eax
<main+23>:   shl    $0x4, %eax
<main+26>:   sub    %eax, %esp
```

Can you explain me what (main+9) to (main+26) is used for?
Why is this done so 'inefficient'?

Comment: is that code produced by gcc in 2004? Happy that days are over! Even the dumbiest optimizer should be able to write better code for main+9 to main+26.

Comment: What is the input (C code?) that produced this assembly? What is the compiler version and flags?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcc on windows generating garbage? windows vs linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552816/gcc-on-windows-generating-garbage-windows-vs-linux) Same prologue. They say it happens only on Windows and GCC 3.X, where and `alloca` is genrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want a full walk-through without doing any research yourself? Sounds legit.

> main+9:    mov    $0x0, %eax

Loads the register `eax` with **hex 0** (=dec 0).

> main+14:   add    $0xf, %eax

Adds **hex F** (= dec 15) to the zero in `eax`.

> main+17:   add    $0xf, %eax

Adds **hex F** (= dec 15) to `eax` again. These three instructions *could* have also been done by

```
movl $0x1e, %eax
```

but who's counting instructions... Anyway, at this point `eax` contains **hex 1E** which is dec 30.

> main+20:   shr    $0x4, %eax

Shifts the contents of `eax` to the right by four bits.

> main+23:   shl    $0x4, %eax

Shifts `eax` right back. Why? Because this clears the lowest four bits. Now eax contains **hex 10** (= dec 16)

> main+26:   sub    %eax, %esp

Substracts `eax` from `esp` (the stack pointer). Since

> main+6:    and    $0xfffffff0, %esp

cleared the lower four bits in `esp` previously, the new `esp` will be sixteen byte aligned, as per ABI. Why not simply use esp after `main+6`? Because on x86, the stack grows *downwards* from the top of memory. Simply masking off the lower bits of `esp` risks clobbering local variables. Hence the subtraction to grow the stack *down* to the sixteen byte boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the walktrough. But couldn't main+9 to main+26 be done by sub $0x10,%esp?

Comment: @red-E: Yes. It's really, really horrible code that uses a lot more instructions than necessary. But it's also generic code: Similar code is used to allocate variable-length stack buffers, so the compiler could re-use code.