# AND operation in function prologue

Tags: assembly

I've just wrapped my head around the concept of function prologues, but this is giving me some trouble.

I wrote a simple hello world program in C then took a look at the assembly code produced:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Assembly (MinGW 4.8.1, Windows 7 32-bit):

```
004016B0   /$  55                         PUSH EBP
004016B1   |.  89E5                       MOV EBP,ESP
004016B3   |.  83E4 F0                    AND ESP,FFFFFFF0
004016B6   |.  83EC 10                    SUB ESP,10
004016B9   |.  E8 A2050000                CALL hello.00401C60
004016BE   |.  C70424 64504000            MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],hello.00405064           ; |ASCII "hello"
004016C5   |.  E8 9E1F0000                CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.puts>                         ; \puts
004016CA   |.  B8 00000000                MOV EAX,0
004016CF   |.  C9                         LEAVE
004016D0   \.  C3                         RETN
```

What is the purpose of ANDing ESP in the third line? I've come across this question: [Why does this function prologue use several instructions to calculate the esp reduction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096708/unclear-main-function-prologue), where 
it is said that

> cleared the lower four bits in esp previously, the new esp will be
>   sixteen byte aligned, as per ABI. Why not simply use esp after main+6?
>   Because on x86, the stack grows downwards from the top of memory.
>   Simply masking off the lower bits of esp risks clobbering local
>   variables. Hence the subtraction to grow the stack down to the sixteen
>   byte boundary.

So my question is, why is that done? Is it better in terms of performance, or is the compiler simply following some fixed standards?

Comment: Please consider leaving an explanation for your downvote the next time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to align the stack on a 16-byte boundary. The reason for aligning stack is so that things that need to be 16-byte aligned, like 16-byte SSE vectors, can be used as local variables in the function.

I should add that this is normally only done by MinGW for `main`. It aligns the stack once at the start of the program, and then keeps the stack 16-byte aligned in other functions by always growing the stack by a multiple of 16-bytes.